# Why I get duplicated todos in todo list?

Tags: javascript

This is the js code

```
let form = document.getElementById('todoForm');
let input = document.getElementById('todoInput');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let todos = [];


const loadTodos = () => {
  let parent = document.getElementById('todoList');
  todos.forEach(todo => {
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = `<li>${todo.text}</li>`
    parent.appendChild(newLi);
  })
}

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let text = input.value;
  let todo = {
    id: todos.length + 1,
    text: text,
    complete: false,
  }
  todos.push(todo);
  loadTodos();
})


window.onload = () => {
  loadTodos();
}
```

When I add a todo for the first time its ok, but the seconed time will print the first todo again include the seconed.

example:

1. first todo
   2.first todo
   3.seconed todo

Comment: You have to empty out the "todoList" element before adding the list; your code always adds the *entire* list.

Comment: You are re-creating each item in list, you need to clear existing ones before loadTodos or simply just create the last added item.

Comment: and how do i do that? any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make another function to handle single todo added, below is your updated code

```
let form = document.getElementById('todoForm');
let input = document.getElementById('todoInput');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let todos = [];


const loadTodos = () => {
    let parent = document.getElementById('todoList');
    todos.forEach(todo => {
        let newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.innerHTML = `<li>${todo.text}</li>`
        parent.appendChild(newLi);
    })
}

const renderNewToDo = (todo) => {
    let parent = document.getElementById('todoList');
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = `<li>${todo.text}</li>`
    parent.appendChild(newLi);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = input.value;
    let todo = {
        id: todos.length + 1,
        text: text,
        complete: false,
    }
    todos.push(todo);
    renderNewToDo(todo);
})


window.onload = () => {
    loadTodos();
}
```